# How to add composite css -webkit-mask-image?

Tags: html, css, webkit

My requirement is to add a mask on top of a div with all the region to have 50% transparency, except a small window in that div which should be 100% opaque.

-by 100% opaque i meant, the content should be fully visible without any mask on that area.

I am also attaching an image mentioning what i am trying to achieve.

I have tried below mentioned mask, but it didn't work out:

```
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image:
    -webkit-linear-gradient(

        left,
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 ,
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 100px ,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100px , 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 300px 

    ),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(

        top,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 ,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50px,
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 50px,
        rgba(0,0,0,1) 100px,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100px,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 150px 
    )
;"
```

[image: Image sowing the requirements]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that by masking with a SVG.

First you need to create the SVG element and add it to DOM:

```
 <svg id='svgOverlay' width='100%' height='100%' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:100000;'>
    <defs>
      <mask id='mask'>
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' fill='white' />
        <rect x='0' y='40' width='200' height='200' fill='black' />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <rect fill='black' width='100%' height='100%' opacity='0.5' mask='url(#mask)' />                
    </g>
  </svg>
```

To position your mask inside your div adjust the styling on the `<svg>` tag (either `fixed` if you need to cover whole page or `absolute` if you are nesting in a div):

```
<svg id='svgOverlay' width='100%' height='100%' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:100000;'>
...
```

This part is your transparent area:

```
...
<rect x='0' y='40' width='200' height='200' fill='black' />
...
```

Adjust x, y, width and height to fit your needs. **The only catch is that if you have selectable content under it, you won't be able to select it by clicking/draging with mouse** - if this is not a problem for you it is a rock solid approach.

Here is a working sample (works in chrome, firefox, opera, IE9+ ): http://codepen.io/easwee/pen/gyExz

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what war required, and it is working just like WOW....just one more question, if u want i can raise it as a seperate question
"Is it posible to add animation in the incresing the width of transparent area, like in this case from width=200 to width=250"....without animation i am able to acheive it by using setAttribute, but is there way to add animation to this.

If you feel that it is seperate discussion all together, I can raise it as seperate question in another thread....

Comment: @Ninja you could animate the transparent area with javascript - the svg  syntax can be manipulated as normal HTML.

Comment: No problems with selection thankfully to pointer-events property. http://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/rxjZzd

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-composite

... `-webkit-mask-composite` takes multiple parameters (when needed). In most cases I'd assume the number of composites match the number of masks.

Couple of things to remember:

- The first mask added is the last that appears in your CSS string, as does the order of the
  compositing string.
- Think sequentially (a new render for each composite iteration) where the "source" is the
  current render of the mask in the iteration, and the destination is the next iteration.

It can be achieved purely with CSS as show in this codepen: http://codepen.io/daleyjem/pen/MYqvqY

First I built out the fully opaque square within the container using the first 2 masks (last 2 in the CSS string) and then I added a 50% opaque box that spanned the whole region with a `source-over`.

There are probably different combinations you can use to achieve the same effect.