# CSS Trick transparent and subtract background

Tags: css, background, transparent, subtraction

I would like make the following what you see in the picture. I have a 100% width background which is transparent and in the middle it has subtracting. What is the way how can I solve this in css?
I tried make one div with 100% width but can I crop or cut the things from the background? The black line is the menu of the site and it has to be position fixed.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you design the photo with the background? Why do you need to achieve this using CSS?

Comment: The black line is the menu of the site and it has to be position fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you can have two solutions:

- First you can use svg masks as @easwee suggested: [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611464/how-to-add-composite-css-webkit-mask-image),
- Second, you can `z-index` your image so that it's always in front of your menu. You won't have the transparent shape you are looking for though... Here is an example:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
}
img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 10; /* z-index to put picture in front of your menu */
  position: relative; /* Don't forget to add this for your z-index to display over position: fixed element */
}
```

```html
<nav>
</nav>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/350/150" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In bibendum leo vitae turpis bibendum, vitae semper est semper. Sed ut posuere lacus. Phasellus eget molestie mi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla porttitor libero orci, a faucibus eros ultricies sed. Morbi urna purus, finibus in volutpat non, bibendum nec nisi. Morbi pellentesque porta justo ac feugiat. Donec ac enim turpis.</p>
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec sollicitudin eget est id consequat. Etiam vehicula velit erat, id molestie nisl dignissim eu. Suspendisse mollis est nunc, ut aliquam quam maximus luctus. Morbi in magna faucibus magna volutpat sollicitudin sit amet quis orci. Mauris vitae neque a purus dapibus euismod quis id neque. Nullam maximus tempor purus, a commodo mi venenatis et.</p>
<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec sollicitudin eget est id consequat. Etiam vehicula velit erat, id molestie nisl dignissim eu. Suspendisse mollis est nunc, ut aliquam quam maximus luctus. Morbi in magna faucibus magna volutpat sollicitudin sit amet quis orci. Mauris vitae neque a purus dapibus euismod quis id neque. Nullam maximus tempor purus, a commodo mi venenatis et.</p>
```